# Algorithm to generate free unlabelled trees uniformly at random

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, trees, algorithmic-randomness

I am implementing an algorithm to generate free unlabelled trees uniformly at random (uar). For this I found [this](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/website/Free%20trees.pdf) paper by Herbert S. Wilf (*The uniform selection of trees*. 1981. In *Journal of Algorithms*). This paper defines the procedure `Free` which generates free unlabelled trees by calling one of two smaller procedures (either `Bicenter` or `Forest`) with a certain probability each. These two procedures, in turn, are based on the *ranrut* procedure, which generates rooted unlabelled trees uar. You can find the reference in *Combinatorial Algorithms For Computers and Calculators*. Albert Nijenhuis and Herbert S. Wilf. 2nd Edition. Academic Press. (I'll try to make this post as self-contained as I can).

First, I'm quite convinced to have managed to implement the *ranrut* procedure so that each rooted unlabelled tree is generated uar. However, I'm having some problems with the algorithm to generate free unlabelled trees ([here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/website/Free%20trees.pdf)) and I was hoping that you could help me. In this post I would like to ask two questions.

---

I have one problem with language. Specifically, with one particular word, which I do not understand in the context of the paper. The word is *adjoined* and appears in the `Forest` procedure, as seen highlighted in this image:

[image]

The image is an extract of Wilf's paper that shows the full procedure `Forest`. Now, the word *adjoined* is used in the sentence

> Then exit with $j$ copies of $T'$ *adjoined* to $\mathcal{F}'$.

- Should *adjoined* be understood here as the disjoint union of graphs? Namely, should I perform the operation $\mathcal{F}' \oplus T'_1 \oplus \cdots T'_j$, where $\oplus$ denotes disjoint union of graphs ? If not, how should I interpret it?

---

Wilf says that, in order to generate uar a forest of $m$ trees, we first choose two integers $(j,d)$ with probability (as shown in the above image)

> $$
> Prob(j,d) = \frac{d\cdot \alpha(m - jd,q) \cdot a_d}{m \cdot \alpha(m,q)}.
> $$

For this we need the values $a_n$ (the number of rooted unlabelled trees of $n$ vertices), and $\alpha(m,q)$ (the number of rooted forests of $m$ vertices whose trees have at most $q$ vertices each).

I have written an algorithm to correctly calculate $a_n$. I know it is correct because I can compare the values obtained with [its integer sequence](https://oeis.org/A000081).

- I would like to know if I'm calculating $\alpha(m,q)$ correctly. However, I haven't been able to find the integer sequences for $\alpha(m,q)$. Do you know where I can find it?

---

I hope to have made my doubts understandable and the questions clear.

Thanks to you all for your time.

---

**Edit**
This post was motivated because my implementation of this algorithm did not generate trees uniformly at random. In my desperation I came here for help. Although the questions above still stand (because the implementation of the above might still be wrong), one of the "bugs" was caused by an error in Wilf's paper. My advisor pointed me to [this](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/graphtheoryusermanual.346702481/view) document (*Graph theory package for Giac/Xcas - Reference Manual*, September 2018) where this error is mentioned and corrected (page 38, footnote 1.1). For the sake of self-containment, I tell you here what the error is and how it has been corrected. The `Free` procedure that Wilf defines in [this](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/website/Free%20trees.pdf) paper, says that in order to generate an $n$-vertex free tree u.a.r. you have to generate a bicentroidal tree with probability $p$, or a random forest of $n-1$ vertices with probability $1-p$ (the roots of this forest are connected to a new vertex). Wilf says that
$$p ={1 + a_{n/2} \choose 2}/a_n$$
where $a_n$ is the number of rooted unlabelled trees of $n$ vertices. As pointed out in the [cited document](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/graphtheoryusermanual.346702481/view) in this edit, the denominator is wrong. Instead of $a_n$, it should be $f_n$, the number of unlabelled free trees on $n$ vertices.

Comment: Based on the images, yes, I say you have the right idea. In your disjoint union, make sure the T'_i are all isomorphic to T'.  Gerhard "Follow The Recipe Very Closely" Paseman, 2019.12.26.

Comment: Okay. That is exactly what I was doing but I wasn't sure at a 100%. Now it only remains the other question of the $\alpha(m,q)$  :)

Comment: I have edited the original post with a correction of a small error in the original paper. However, I would appreciate to have my other questions answered, since they refer to parts of my code that still need debugging.

Comment: I wonder if you actually need this algorithm, or you just need one fast in practice.  Walk at random on $K_n$ until every vertex is visited (about $n\log n$ steps on average).  Mark the edge along which each vertex was visited for the first time.  That's a uniform random free tree.  It's very fast: 6000 trees/sec on 1000 vertices for me.

Comment: I like the idea of using a simpler algorithm. This would alleviate my job a lot more. However, I think you are describing a procedure for generating u.a.r. labelled free trees (as described by Aldous [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15859n/RelatedWork/AldousRandomTrees.pdf)). But I want to generate u.a.r. unlabelled free trees.

I hope I didn't misunderstand your proposal. If I didn't, the only question that remains unanswered in the original post is to find the integer sequences of $\alpha(m,q)$.

Comment: Why don't you compare your algorithm and your calculation of $\alpha(m,q)$ with the source code on which the cited documentation is based? In particular, this function: https://github.com/marohnicluka/giac/blob/master/graphe.cc#L7149

Comment: Yes, thank you. I compared my algorithm and the computation of the $\alpha(m,q)$ in the link you gave and the numbers coincide, up to $n=~400$.

Comment: I know this is not what the "answers" are for, but I see no other way of reaching you, unfortunately. I am currently working on implementing Wilf's algorithm myself and I would like to contact you about some problems I am having. Is there any way I can reach you? Kind regards.

Comment: @Sam, I've just read your comment (I am very sorry! three years later...). I don't think I ever got a notification of your comment. If you are still struggling, go to my profile in MO, and you'll find a link to my webpage, which contains all necessary contact info. If you just want to see the implementation in C++, see [this](https://github.com/LAL-project/linear-arrangement-library/blob/master/lal/generate/rand_ulab_free_trees.hpp?ts=4) and [this](https://github.com/LAL-project/linear-arrangement-library/blob/master/lal/generate/rand_ulab_free_trees.cpp?ts=4) files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the effort of several people, I got the answers I was looking for. I write this so that other people in the future can have a direct answer to the questions above without having to read the comments.

- The first question was whether the word **adjoined** (in the `Forest` procedure) referred to **disjoint union** of graphs. [This comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349153/algorithm-to-generate-free-unlabelled-trees-uniformly-at-random#comment874770_349153) written by [Gerhard Paseman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3402/gerhard-paseman) confirmed this. Thanks to this comment and careful reading of the `Free` procedure, any interpretation of the word **adjoined** other than **disjoint union** should be ruled out.
- The second question was about the calculation of the numbers $\alpha(m,q)$. [Timothy Budd](https://mathoverflow.net/users/47484/timothy-budd) added [a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349153/algorithm-to-generate-free-unlabelled-trees-uniformly-at-random#comment877764_349153) where I was pointed to an implementation of this algorithm where I could find the computation of $\alpha(m,q)$. Budd advised me to compare the result of that algorithm with mine. This proved useful, and the results of my implementation and those of the code to which I was pointed coincide.

Thanks to everyone who helped in finding the answers to my questions, even to those who did not answer them directly. I really appreciate your help.