# Random sample of spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, spanning-tree

In a complete graph with $n$ vertices there are $n^{n-2}$ spanning trees.

I want to get a random sample of size $k$ from the set of all spanning trees.

The most basic and naive idea is to generate all spanning trees and select the required sample. But that's costly.

Are there some other approaches? Possibly, enumerating them without generating?

The ideal way would be to set a one-to-one correspondence between a natural number and a spanning tree.

So, for example I generate a random sample of numbers, say $(7,12,5)$, and then, based on these numbers, I get spanning trees.

Comment: Do you want just random, or uniformly random among the $n^{n-2}$ trees?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen , can you explain the difference?

Comment: Some methods might give you a nonuniform random sample, i.e. some trees might be more probable than some others.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen ,  two options: uniform and normal.

Comment: Propp and Wilson have a nice Monte Carlo method using coupling from the past to ensure you know when to terminate the iteration: "How to Get a Perfectly Random Sample from a Generic Markov Chain and Generate a Random Spanning Tree of a Directed Graph" https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~scs/Projects/Trees/Theory/ProppWilson1998.pdf

Comment: @Paul, I don't understand what is "normal" distribution over trees. Can you clarify?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen, I'm not an expert in this field. I mean that sample can have uniform or normal distribution.

Comment: Uniform distribution, over a discrete set such as "all spanning trees of this graph", simply means that when you pick one element (one tree), each tree has the same probability of being picked. I have no idea what "normal" might be in this context, and if you don't know that either, I guess we can safely ignore that suggestion.

Comment: Except for dealing with unlabelled trees instead of with labelled ones the paper cited in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349153/algorithm-to-generate-free-unlabelled-trees-uniformly-at-random) MO question seems to be closely related

Comment: @ManfredWeis: generating (uniformly) random unlabeled trees is a much more difficult problem than this one of generating (uniformly) random labeled trees.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen , each tree has the same probability of being picked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach is to generate $k$ random [Prüfer sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence#:%7E:text=In%20combinatorial%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Pr%C3%BCfer,by%20a%20simple%20iterative%20algorithm.) and then convert each sequence into a tree.  It is also well-known that performing a random walk on $K_n$ will generate a random spanning tree on $n$ vertices, so this is an easy way to sample a random spanning tree without generating them all.

Comment: Prüfer I understand, but how is the random walk defined? Can the walk go back to already visited vertices? Otherwise I don't understand how it can generate any branching trees.

Comment: The random walk can return to earlier vertices: At each step, it goes to a uniformly chosen random neighbor of its current vertex. For each vertex $v$ other then the starting vertex, let $e_v$ be the edge that was traveled right BEFORE the first time that the walk reaches $v$. The set of edges $\{ e_v  \}$ turns out to be a spanning tree, chosen uniformly at random. See Aldous https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15859n/RelatedWork/AldousRandomTrees.pdf .

Comment: That said, if you specifically want spanning trees of $K_n$, Prufer codes are probably easier.

Comment: Is there a linear time algorithm for turning a Prüfer sequence into a tree?  The usual algorithm, for example in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prüfer_sequence), doesn't seem to be linear.  I suspect it just needs a better data structure.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I suspect that a linear algorithm doesn't exist because the algorithm needs to sort vertices according to label values; that seems to be necessary for any unique encoding scheme and thus $O(n \log\, n)$ can't be improved.
Would be an interesting question if the degree sequence uniquely encodes trees; that sequence can be calculated in $O(n)$

Comment: @ManfredWeis Sorting of small integers takes linear time with a bucket sort.

Comment: @ManfredWeis Degree sequence does not encode spanning tree. EG there are two isomorphism classes of trees of $10$ vertices with degree sequence $1^6 3^4$: One is the "snowflake" with edges $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$, $(0,3)$, $(1,4)$, $(1,5)$, $(2,6)$, $(2,7)$, $(3,8)$, $(3,9)$; the other is the "caterpillar" with edges $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(0,4)$, $(0,5)$, $(1,6)$, $(2,7)$, $(3,8)$, $(3,9)$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay In a very naive computation model, you can't beat $n \log n$ steps because you need $n \log n$ bits of input data to encode all the different trees, and you need to look at all the bits. I imagine you are thinking about some sort of model where you can compare $\log n$ bit integers in $O(1)$ time, but you need to be more careful about specifying your computation model if you want to do something like that.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer  I wasn't asking for linear time in the sense of bit complexity and agree that is impossible. I was assuming the model that is used most commonly for combinatorial algorithms, namely that elementary operations with integers of value $O(n)$, i.e. $O(\log n)$ bits, take $O(1)$ time. Otherwise operations like incrementing an array index or accessing an array element would have $O(\log n)$ cost and almost all algorithms advertised as "linear time" would not be.

Comment: So, looking at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Labeled_Tree_from_Pr%C3%BCfer_Sequence , it looks like we need a data structure which represents a subset $L$ of $[n]$ such that finding the smallest element, and deleting an arbitrary element from $L$, are both $O(1)$. (This is "the list" in the terminology of the link.) It seems to me that we can do this by combining an array and a doubly linked list, as follows:

Comment: Let $A$ be an array with entries $A[1]$, $A[2]$, ..., $A[n]$, $A[n+1]$. Each element of the array is a pair of integers. Set $L' = L \cup \{ n+1 \}$, which we consider as ordered circularly. If $j \not\in L'$, then $A[j]$ is $(0,0)$. If $j \in L'$, and $i$ and $k$ are the elements of $L'$ before and after $j$, then $A[j] = (i,k)$. Then we can delete $j$ by reading $A[j]$ to find the elements $i$ and $k$ before and after it, and editing $A[i]$, $A[j]$, $A[k]$ appropriately, and we can find the location of the smallest element by looking at $A[n+1]$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm for unranking and ranking spanning trees due to Colbourn, Day and Nel which is described in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0196677489900163

You can compute the number of spanning trees, say $K$ and then generate a random integer in the range $1$ to $K$, say $\ell$ and apply the unranking algorithm to get the $\ell$’th spanning tree.

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic solution would be to randomly shuffle the set of edges and assgning them their index in that random sequence as their weight and finally calculate the Minimum-weight Spanning Tree of the thus weighted edge-set with any of the standard algorithms for Minimum-weight Spanning Trees.
Repeat $k$ times to get a random sample of the desired cardinality from the set of spanning trees.

The randomness of the so generated sample depends of course on the quality of shuffling process.

Comment: It should be noted that this process does not yield an uniform distribution over all spanning trees, even if the graph is $K_n$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109978/why-a-random-minimum-spanning-tree-is-not-an-uniform-spanning-tree

Comment: @hdur the posed question did not make any restrictions on the desired distribution and without knowing the intended use, resp. constraints, there can't be a single 'best' algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to generate a spanning tree in a non-uniform way. I added it as a answer, because the exercise  that is non-uniform is interesting enough.

Start with the set of $n$-vertices 1,..,n. Pick a random vertex and remove it. Pick a second vertex and leave it in the set. Connect the two vertices. Then repeat until there is only one vertex left in that set.